# Как разбить строчку сгруппировав ее по ключам?

Tags: php, массивы, строки, сортировка

Есть строчка вида

```
3199996|Amazing Dubbing||3199114|AniDUB||3204688|AniLibria||3204934|AniMaunt||3198662|AnimeVost||3199009|AniPlay||3199879|AniRise||3198674|AniStar||3210309|Anything Group||3199048|KBK||3201994|KitsuneBox||3200688|Risens Team||3199154|SHIZA Project||3199180|TAKEOVER Project|||3206565|AniDUB||3214108|AniLibria||3204770|AnimeVost||3214571|AniRise||3204751|AniStar||3213831|Anything Group||3206322|KBK||3211200|KitsuneBox||3205028|Risens Team||3210273|SHIZA Project|||3216986|AniDUB||3218426|AniLibria||3214254|AnimeVost||3219614|AniRise||3214057|AniStar||3214746|Anything Group||3219664|KBK||3214608|Risens Team||3215849|SHIZA Project|||3218870|AnimeVost||3218862|AniStar||3219909|Anything Group||3218760|Risens Team
```

Все что я могу сделать с этой кашей

```
    $str = "3199996|Amazing Dubbing||3199114|AniDUB||3204688|AniLibria||3204934|AniMaunt||3198662|AnimeVost||3199009|AniPlay||3199879|AniRise||3198674|AniStar||3210309|Anything Group||3199048|KBK||3201994|KitsuneBox||3200688|Risens Team||3199154|SHIZA Project||3199180|TAKEOVER Project|||3206565|AniDUB||3214108|AniLibria||3204770|AnimeVost||3214571|AniRise||3204751|AniStar||3213831|Anything Group||3206322|KBK||3211200|KitsuneBox||3205028|Risens Team||3210273|SHIZA Project|||3216986|AniDUB||3218426|AniLibria||3214254|AnimeVost||3219614|AniRise||3214057|AniStar||3214746|Anything Group||3219664|KBK||3214608|Risens Team||3215849|SHIZA Project|||3218870|AnimeVost||3218862|AniStar||3219909|Anything Group||3218760|Risens Team";

$mas = explode("|||", $str);

$str_result="";

foreach ($mas as $value) {

    $mas1 = explode("||", $value);

    foreach ($mas1 as $value1) {

        $mas2 = explode("|", $value1);

        $str_result .= $mas2[1]."-".$mas2[0]."<br>";

    }

}

echo $str_result;
```

Результат выполнения кода

```
Amazing Dubbing-3199996
AniDUB-3199114
AniLibria-3204688
AniMaunt-3204934
AnimeVost-3198662
AniPlay-3199009
AniRise-3199879
AniStar-3198674
Anything Group-3210309
KBK-3199048
KitsuneBox-3201994
Risens Team-3200688
SHIZA Project-3199154
TAKEOVER Project-3199180
AniDUB-3206565
AniLibria-3214108
AnimeVost-3204770
AniRise-3214571
AniStar-3204751
Anything Group-3213831
KBK-3206322
KitsuneBox-3211200
Risens Team-3205028
SHIZA Project-3210273
AniDUB-3216986
AniLibria-3218426
AnimeVost-3214254
AniRise-3219614
AniStar-3214057
Anything Group-3214746
KBK-3219664
Risens Team-3214608
SHIZA Project-3215849
AnimeVost-3218870
AniStar-3218862
Anything Group-3219909
Risens Team-3218760
```

Задача: преобразовать строчку из исходного вида в такую

```
AnimeVost|3198662|3204770|3214254|3218870||AniStar|3198674|3204751|3214057|3218862||Anything Group|3210309|3213831|3214746|3219909||Risens Team|3200688|3205028|3214608|3218760||AniDUB|3199114|3206565|3216986||AniLibria|3204688|3214108|3218426||.....||Amazing Dubbing|3199996
```

AnimeVost, AniStar и т.д. - это группы людей, 3198662, 3204770 и т.д. - это айди произведений, созданных этими группами людей. Мне необходимо отсортировать строчку так, чтоб присвоить группе все id, которые ей принадлежат. Причем та группа у которой больше id идет первой, далее та у которой меньше чем у первой и т.д. (по убыванию кол-ва id)

Comment: а что здесь ключи, как строчку разбивать, что такое кол-во набора чисел?

Comment: Все таки запутал. Текстовая часть (AniLibria, AniDUB...) - это группы. Слева от них id произведения, отделенные от группы символом | Сами группы разделены символом || Строка состоит из четырех частей, которые разделены между собой символом |||

Comment: ничего не понял про сортировку. у вас в приведенной строке есть  4 группы с 4мя ID, в результирующей явно не по количеству сортировка, и не по алфавиту

Comment: Отсортировано по наборам, разделенным символом ||| Таких наборов 4 если присмотреться. Внутри них указаны группы людей и id их произведений. Мне нужно привести строчку к виду: группа|id|id|id|id||следгруппа|id...

Comment: опишите нормально задачу. что и как разбить надо и т.п. с примером как делим строку, что получаем, что делаем дальше. Отредактируйте свой вопрос с помощью [edit]

Comment: @DomiToriKun я там в ответе написал код, который делает массив из вашей строки. Попробуйте может на нем объяснить, что надо. Или возьмите оттуда характерные куски и покажите результат

Comment: изменил стартпост, расписал понятнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поделить можно так, но что потом то делать?

```
$all = explode('|||', $str);

foreach($all as $i) {
   $temp = explode('||', $i); 
   $arr = [];  
   foreach($temp as $x) {
      list($v, $k) = explode('|', $x); 
      $arr[] = [$k =>$v];
   }
   $arr = array_merge_recursive(...$arr);
   $res[] = $arr;
}

print_r($res);
```

https://eval.in/946366

Comment: дальше на выходе строчки мне нужно получить такое
`AnimeVost-3198662,3204770,3214254,3218870.
AniStar-3198674,3204751,3214057,3218862.
Anything Group-3210309,3213831,3214746,3219909.
Risens Team-3200688,3205028,3214608,3218760.
AniDUB-3199114,3206565,3216986.
AniLibria-3204688,3214108,3218426.
Amazing Dubbing-3199996`

Comment: добавьте в конец моего кода `$res = array_merge_recursive(...$res);` и  остается его отсортировать при помощи usort(). Таких примеров множество

Comment: Спасибо. Как то пропустил мимо глаз в гугле эту функцию для слияния массивов. То что нужно

Answer (score 0):

```
 $str="3199996|Amazing Dubbing||3199114|AniDUB||3204688|AniLibria||3204934|AniMaunt||3198662|AnimeVost||3199009|AniPlay||3199879|AniRise||3198674|AniStar||3210309|Anything Group||3199048|KBK||3201994|KitsuneBox||3200688|Risens Team||3199154|SHIZA Project||3199180|TAKEOVER Project|||3206565|AniDUB||3214108|AniLibria||3204770|AnimeVost||3214571|AniRise||3204751|AniStar||3213831|Anything Group||3206322|KBK||3211200|KitsuneBox||3205028|Risens Team||3210273|SHIZA Project|||3216986|AniDUB||3218426|AniLibria||3214254|AnimeVost||3219614|AniRise||3214057|AniStar||3214746|Anything Group||3219664|KBK||3214608|Risens Team||3215849|SHIZA Project|||3218870|AnimeVost||3218862|AniStar||3219909|Anything Group||3218760|Risens Team";
 $str=str_replace('|||','||',$str);
 $mass=explode("||",  $str);
 $str2="";
foreach ($mass as $key => $value) {
 $mass2=explode("|",  $value);
$str2=$str2.",".$mass2[0].",".$mass2[1];
}
$str2=substr($str2, 1);
 $mass3=explode(",",  $str2);
 $c=count($mass3);
 for($i=0;$i<=$c;$i++){
if($i & 1){$arrr[$mass3[$i-1]]=$mass3[$i]; $unic_text[$mass3[$i]]=$mass3[$i-1];}
 }
foreach ($unic_text as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($arrr as $key1 => $val) {
if($key==$val){
$masiv[$key]=$masiv[$key]."|".$key1;
  }}
}
print_r($masiv);
```

Как-то так, потом usort, а уже потом implode. Хотя думаю есть более элегантное решение.

Comment: по рукам бы вам настучать, за такое форматирование кода

Comment: Увы такая ересь хранится в бд. И из каши хотелось бы сделать креветки)

Comment: Уж извините, я любитель psr не читал ((((

Comment: чтобы отступы в тексте расставить psr читать не надо